# Project created with "tns create" give error with any "ng generate' command

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Just trying to learn Nativescript using the Nativescript CLI and an Angular Framewok.

```
tns create myapp --ng
```

Then after answering the questions, I move on to:

```
ng generate --help
```

Which gives this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/config'
See "/tmp/ng-V5J95L/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The log file contains:

```
[error] Error: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/config'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/@nativescript/schematics/src/angular-project-parser.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Comment: Same issue here tns version 6.0.3 angular version 8.1.3 angular cli version 8.2.0

Comment: The ng command only gives this error when inside a NativeScript project directory. It's work outside the directory. Funnily enough I think I fixed it. I was accidentally using Node.js version 12 which is not the LTS version

Comment: @ModJohn,what did you do to fix this? what version of node then did you use?

Comment: Yes, I had accidentally used Node.js version 12. The fix was to use the LTS version 10.

Answer (score 4):

```
npm i -D @nativescript/schematics
```

then

```
npm i -D @angular/cli
```

restart the terminal/ command line and then again

```
ng g c <Component/name>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me turned out be be because I had installed and was using version 12.x of Node.js, the fix was to use the Long Term Support (LTS) version 10.x of Node.js.